# Prolog - check if list is empty []

Tags: list, prolog

I am just trying to figure out how to check if a list is empty, I put together something that checks the length of the list, and additionally should check to see if the list isn't empty.

```
% Gives the length of a list.
listlength([]     , 0 ).
listlength([_|Xs] , L ):- 
    listlength(Xs,N), 
    L is N+1. 

% checks to see that the length of the list is greater than or equal to 3 and not empty.
check_length( [] ).
check_length( L  ):-
    listlength(L, Len),
    Len >= 3,
    L \== [].    %This is the bit of code I'm having problems with 
                  it should be false if the list is just [] or empty.
```

I am a student so I don't necessarily need a straight answer I'm just trying to figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: If the length >= 3, it can't be empty; if it is empty, the length will be 0.  You don't need the extra term.

Comment: That's what I thought but check length returns true when I pass it []

Comment: `listLength` doesn't *return* anything: it tries to make a true statement.  If you pass it an empty list and a variable for the second argument, it will bind that second argument to 0.

Comment: Sorry I'm still getting used to prolog, but either way even though it seems to bind the empty list [] to 0, I'm still getting that when I use check_length that it is true when I pass [].

Comment: Since you have the fact `check_length([]).` then `check_length(L)` succeeds if `L` is empty. But you are saying you want `check_length(L)` to be true only if length is greater than 3. So you need to get rid of the fact `check_length([]).`

Comment: Is there a very particular reason why you are not using the built-in predicate `length/2`? It must be one of the most fundamental Prolog predicates, and you cannot easily write useful Prolog code without it. With it, `length(List, Len), Len >= 3` is all you would have to do (sorry for the straight answer).

Comment: Another (less scalable) way to check for length of `L` being >= 3 is: `L = [_,_,_|_]`, which is true if and only if length of `L` is >= 3.

Answer (score 7):

You don't need to explicitly test for L being an empty list; it having a length > 0 establishes that.

And you already know how to test for a list not being empty, since you used it in `listLength`: `L=[_|_]` (that is, `L` is a list with at least 1 element).

Answer (score 2):

The question is "how to check if a list is empty". By definition, an empty list is a list with no elements, i.e., the [] list. You could simply check if your list unifies with that.

Answer (score 2):

something that worked for me was:

empty_List(List) :- List = [].

Answer (score 1):

Another option, if you're limited in what you can use:

`is_empty(List):- not(member(_,List)).`

Which checks if the given list has any members, and returns the negation of that.

`[]` => No members, is empty.

`[foo]` => Member exists, is not empty.

Answer (score 0):

```
%calculate the length
len([],0).
len([_|T],N) :- len(T,X), N is X+1.

%check the length
isEmpty(L) :- len(L,X),X=:=0.
```

Comment: Just say `isEmpty([]).`

Comment: Very true false. That is called over-engineering :) This clearly shows I am still a newbie in Prolog :)